# Multilingual Search in Alfresco

Tags: search, multilingual, alfresco

I want to achieve the multilingual search in Alfresco.

And I know that in Alfresco there is a multilingual function, you could upload the different language version of the document.

But I don't know how can I related them together. That is when I search "cat", I want to get the Japanese version of the document with "ねこ"(means 'cat') in it.

But I can only get the English version as a search result.

Could anyone tell me how can I get all the related document (all the translated version of this document) as search result? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Alfresco [Wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Multilingual_Document_Support#Indexing_Support). If you have your locale set to jap, then you should only get the japanese version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to refer through this documentation in Alfresco. http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/tasks/tuh-multilingual.html